# Trying to add frames in \AtBeginDocument destroys slides layout

Tags: beamer, layout

I guess I've basically got the same question as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150623/move-beamer-header-down). But copying `.sty` content into my header by hand doesn't feel like the right solution. So let's have a fresh start:

For some slides I create, the first slides will always be the same. So I've tried to include them via `\AtBeginDocument` in my header. However, slides defined here are moved down a bit. I can't explain why and the only fix I found is mentioned above.

Here is a minimal (working) example:

```
%%%%% THIS WOULD BE THE HEADER %%%%%%
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\metroset{block=fill}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \begin{frame}{wrong}
        This doesn't work.
    \end{frame}
}

%%%%% THIS THE ACTUAL DOCUMENT %%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{right}
        This works.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

That turns out like this:

[image]

**EDIT:** As requested by [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) I will try to give a little more context why I think `\AtBeginDocument` is the right solution for me:

The part marked as the header would actually only be an input to my document. If I wouldn't use something similar to `\AtBeginDocument` that can add content to my document from the header file I would need to duplicate this piece of code in every document. That does not seem like proper code design to me.

Thanks for your help in advance :)
Pascal

Comment: Why not just store the frames in a `.tex` file and use `\input`?

Comment: @AlanMunn That's what I did before. But I thought this would be the smarter way if I input the header anyways. The extra `\input` looks like unnecessary code duplication to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, this. If you use `\AtBeginDocument` you duplicate the code in each document. If you store the code in a file and use `\input` then you're only adding a single line of code to each document. No duplication to speak of.

Comment: I am not talking about code duplication of the `\begin{frame}...` part there are multiple solutions to get around this. But if I do it the way you suggested, every document starts with `\begin{document} \input...`. This feels like an unnecessary (duplicated) line right after the document begin.

Comment: Even so, you're also going to have to duplicate the `\AtBeginDocument` in each document. Or are you building a custom class that loads `beamer` and then wants to add the slides using `\AtBeginDocument`?  If so, that wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: @AlanMunn Everything before the `begin{document}...` is saved in a separate (header) file and input via `input{myHeader}`. I could modify that in the question. (Split the code as I would split the files.) But I feel like the way it is written down now makes it easy to play around with.

Comment: No, don't edit the code, because you're right, it makes it easier to play with but do explain what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example does the following:

- The original definition of `\begin{frame}` is stored as `\oldframe`.
- `\begin{frame}` is redefined to first reset its definition to `\oldframe`, to then call the macro `\mystartframe`, and then to call the original `\begin{frame}`. That means: The first time, `\begin{frame}` appears in the document, the macro `\mystartframe` is executed, and from all following calls, `\begin{frame}` is just `\begin{frame}`.
- In `\mystartframe`, I create the frame that you want to have at the start of each presentation.

Thus, instead of using `\AtBeginDocument` to let `\begin{document}` trigger the output of the first slide, I use the first occurrence of `\begin{frame}` for that purpose. Of course, if your presentations typically don't start with a `\begin{frame}` but e.g. with a `\section`, you can use that as a hook instead.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\metroset{block=fill}
\let\oldframe\frame
\def\frame{\let\frame\oldframe\mystartframe\frame}
\newcommand{\mystartframe}{
    \begin{frame}{wrong}
        This doesn't work.
    \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{right}
        This works.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]